# SSM Parameter Store giving timeout for any operation from a EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-parameter-store

I created a EC2 role with the following permissions in cloudformation:

```
Policies:
    - PolicyName: ec2-test-poilcy
      PolicyDocument: |
        {   "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
             {
              "Action": [
                  "ssm:DescribeParameters"
              ],
              "Resource": "*",
              "Effect": "Allow"
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                       "ssm:PutParameter",
                        "ssm:DeleteParameter",
                        "ssm:GetParameterHistory",
                        "ssm:GetParametersByPath",
                        "ssm:GetParameters",
                        "ssm:GetParameter",
                        "ssm:DeleteParameters"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:REGION:ACCOUNT-ID:parameter/*"
            }
            ]
        }
```

And Attached the above role to my EC2 instance but, I was not able perform any SSM Parameter Store operations, I just get no response and after some couple of minutes, I get a timeout.

for example:

```
aws ssm get-parameter --name test --region us-east-2

Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://ssm.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"
```

After trying various things, I attached the **AdministratorAccess policy** too, but it was still not responding to any ssm operations.

**UPDATE**

After spending hours, I realised that timeout error is only happening
for region: us-east-2

```
aws ssm get-parameter --name testing --region us-east-1
```

The above command ran successfully by using a different region .

Comment: SSM Parameter Store and Secrets Manager are two completely separate services. You have mixed them up in your question to the point that it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MarkB Sorry, I meant systems manager there but now I have corrected it now, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Please explain what "not responding" means. Does it just sit there for a bit and timeout?

Comment: @MarkB after some couple of minutes I get a timeout error, i.e : Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://ssm.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"

Comment: It sounds like your EC2 instance does not have Internet access. Is it in a VPC subnet without a route to the Internet?

Comment: @MarkB No, The subnet I attached is a public one with internet access

Comment: And the EC2 instance has a public IP assigned to it?

Comment: Can you successfully run a different AWS command, such as `aws s3 ls`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, after I have attached AdministratorAccess policy, `aws s3 ls ` is running fine

Comment: @MarkB Yes, Auto-assign public IPv4 address has been enabled

Answer (score 2):

Just to close my question as I found the problem, I am answering this myself, and hoping it helps someone else debugging.

I have used the below command for DNS info:

```
dig ssm.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

I got a response, In which I was able to observe that DNS is pointing to private IP:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
ssm.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. 60 IN  A   xx.xx.xx.xx7 (private ip)
```

But the correct DNS resolution would be something like this:

```
    ;; ANSWER SECTION:
ssm.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. 60 IN  A   52.95.21.xxx
```

After spending some hours figuring out why, I found that it was due to the use of an unnecessary vpc endpoint for ssm service, So I removed it and now I am able to get a proper response for ssm operations  for us-east-2 region.

Comment: I just ran into this same situation! Thank you. FYI the logs look like this from AWS SSM if anybody else runs into this:

[AWS ssm undefined 20.499s 3 retries]

Answer (score 0):

Add HTTPS(443) Inbound Rule to security groups associated with VPC Endpoint allowing HTTPS(443) Inbound Rule for instance security group.

We can associate up to 5 Security Groups to VPC Endpoint.
If you're running your command from any EC2 instance, security group associated with the instance should be same as any security group associated with VPC endpoint, Or VPC endpoint associated security group should allow HTTPS(443) Inbound Rule to your instance security group.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).